# C# - How to access a class level variable from a timer elapsed event in multi-threaded class

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, rabbitmq

I am having a class that has a `timer`, on timer elapsed I need to check a class level variable `_isModelShutdown` to determine whether to raise an event or not. The problem is that the timer is not able to get the latest value from the class level variable `_isModelShutdown`. I tried it by changing that variable to `static` variable, but that doesn't solve my problem, because this class is called by multiple threads. So, when I am in timer elapsed, the variable seems to get the default value of `false` instead of `true` which was set by an `Consumer_Channel_ModelShutdown` event saying shutdown happened. I think that another thread has already updated the static variable to false.

Workflow: When channel shutdown happens, `Consumer_Channel_ModelShutdown` is fired, that sets `_isModelShutdown=true`. Timer should check for `_isModelShutdown==true` to invoke `Channel_Failure` event. The reason why i can't do all this in the `Consumer_Channel_ModelShutdown` event is that RabbitMQ says shutdown callback is not a safe place to open another channel as it throws time out error on channel creation code. Hope this gives more clarity to the problem.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public event Func<string> Channel_Failure;
    IModel consumerChannel = null;
    private static bool _isModelShutdown = false;
    public SomeClass(RabbitMQConnectionInfo rabbitMQConnectionInfo, Func<string> handleFailure)
    {
        if (handleFailure != null)
        {
           Channel_Failure = handleFailure;
        }
        consumerChannel = rabbitMQConnectionInfo.Connection.CreateModel();
        // Some more code
        if (connected) return;
        StartTimer((int)reconnectionInterval);
    }

    private void StartTimer(int waitIntervalBeforeReconnecting)
    {
        double interval = 30000;
        var retryTimer = new Timer(interval)
        {
            AutoReset = true //run once
        };
        retryTimer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            RetryTimerElapsed((Timer)sender);
        }
        retryTimer.Start();
    }

    private void RetryTimerElapsed(IDisposable sender)
    {
       if (_isModelShutdown) // This is the problem statement, how to access class level variable??
       {
           Channel_Failure?.Invoke(source);
           _isModelShutdown = false; 
       }
    }

    private void Consumer_Channel_ModelShutdown(object sender, Client.ShutdownEventArgs reason)
    {
        _isModelShutdown = true;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this scenario, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Static is definitely the wrong approach. Whats not working about this solution? Also timers are threaded, there is a chance `_isModelShutdown`  is stale

Comment: You don't state what's your problem...

Comment: I have updated the question stating my problem. With non-static, i am not getting the current `_isModelShutdown` value. It always return `false`. With static, it works but inconsistently, as other threads seems to reset `isModelShutdown` to `false`.

Comment: Maybe make your boolean `volatile` so that you'll always read non-stale data?